# How to convert integer number so that they have n decimal places in PostgreSQL SELECT

Tags: postgresql

How can numbers converted so that they have n decimal places?

I want to convert all numbers of a column so that they have three decimal places.
For example the query result should look like this

```
Amount
3.000
2.511
3.200
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html

```
select to_char(amount, '999D999') as "Amount"
  from your_table;
```